# Uncaught ReferenceError: documet is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple javascript to create a textbox however when running the code the console log in chromium gives the following error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: documet is not defined`

This is my html5 doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<main>
<input type="button" name="textbox" value="Create a textbox"    onClick="create_textbox();" />
<div id="content" class="content"><p>test</p></div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript:

```
function create_textbox() {
var content = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
var div = document.getElementById("content");
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=content+"<p>test</p>";
var input = documet.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
var i = 0;
input.name = String("textbox"+i++);
div.appendChild(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it using `document`, not `documet` (note the `n` before the `t`), in this line:

```
var input = documet.createElement("input");
// Add n here ----^
```

Comment: well this is embarrassing... thank's this resolved it!